# How Can I Access SharePoint Site By Accessing Local Address

Tags: xampp, office365, redirect

We have PHP based site host on (XAMPP) locally configured which we can access this site by typing dashboard.xxx.com. we have made entry in local DNS against this dashboard.xxx.com.

I have setpup sharepoint site on office365 which can be access through

https://crescentpk.sharepoint.com/sites/portal

I want to replaced my local server with above sharepoint site but I do not want to change URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're strictly interested in having the "dashboard.xxx.com" forwarding respond on the network served by your internal DNS, then here's a couple options:

1. Leverage the existing PHP site infrastructure to use Mod_rewrite (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html). Forwards all requests for *dashboard.xxx.com* to *https://crescentpk.sharepoint.com/sites/portal*
2. Modify your local DNS records to forward the cname dashboard.xxx.com to your SP site collection URL.

If you're looking to meet your URL requirements on the global intranet, unfortunately there's no means to direct your cname to a specific Office 365 private Site Collection, since the server path portion of the URL is not controlled by DNS, and there is no URL rewriting at that level provided by Office 365.